# How to convert a string to an array using angular filter and use in `ng-repeat`

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

I am receving a string from back-end. that need to be converted as an array then it need to send on `ng-repeate`, how to do that?

i ma familiar filter for using `array` value manipulation. but how to convert a string in to an array for `ng-repeate'

I am preferring filter for generic usage.

here is the code :

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';

  $scope.string = "1. Submittals in progress 2. Structural works in progress in S2 & S3 3. Structural works in progress in N4. 4. Childrens Mall pedestal and steel fabrication."


});

app.filter('string2array', function( string ) {

    return string.match(/\b\d+\.\s+(.+?)\s*(?=\b\d+\. |\s*$)/g); //converted as array.

});
```

HTML :

```
 <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repat="item in string">{{string}}</li>
    </ul>
```

[Live Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/xkNokZn5TUX8QssxKokM)

I am looking the out put like this:

```
<ul>
<li> Submittals in progress </li> //see the number removed.
<li> Structural works in progress in S2 & S3 </li>
<li> Structural works in progress in N4. </li> //end has the dot
<li> Childrens Mall pedestal and steel fabrication. </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Change your filter syntax like this:

   ```
   var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

   app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
     $scope.name = 'World';

   $scope.string = "1. Submittals in progress 2. Structural works in progress in S2 & S3 3. Structural works in progress in N4. 4. Childrens Mall pedestal and steel fabrication."


   });

   app.filter('string2array', function() {
       return function(string){
          return string.match(/\b\d+\.\s+(.+?)\s*(?=\b\d+\. |\s*$)/g);    //converted as array.
      }
   } );
   ```
2. use the filter in the HTML like this:

   ```
   <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
    <ul>
     <li ng-repeat="item in string | string2array">{{item}}</li>
   </ul>
   ```

see edited [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/yvd1o8QJmvjPTCQxVS7I?p=preview)